# View ftp exceptions in windows

Tags: windows-7, ftp, iis

I'm trying to create a custom authentication assembly for my FTP site. I've done everything from creating the assembly to registering it in GAC and registering a custom authentication provider in the ftp authentication section in IIS.

I've got everything set up on the ftp site and now I'm trying to test the new login to it, and of course it's not working from the first try.
It just says:

> Win32 error: Error details: An error occured during the authentication
>   process.

I'm gonna need something more descriptive than that(for example what caused the error)

Where do I need to look for exceptions from ftp in windows? I've checked out Event Viewer but I'm not really sure where to look.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried the ftp log in `%system drive%/Inetpub/Logs/LogFiles` but there's no useful info there too.

Maybe I need to set it up for more detailed logging?

Comment: What kind of method of authentication are you using? Where is your FTP site located? Have you attached a debugger to your process? How are you testing it?

Comment: I'm using a custom managed code FTP authentication provider. my ftp site is located in inetpub. I haven't attached a debugger to my process because I don't think it can be attached because the .dll is in GAC of .NET. I'm testing it by providing a valid username and password(I don't see any other way).